# Where to configure which password sudo needs

Tags: sudo

on some OS `sudo` requires the users password, on others it's `root`'s password.

Where is the config file to decide on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I think you're referring to `su` and not `sudo`, `sudo` can do this.

There are a few parameters (for `/etc/sudoers`) related to this behavior.

`rootpw`: This causes sudo to require entering root's password.
`runaspw`: This causes sudo to require entering the target user's password.

These are both options you'd set as a default. Meaning you can't specify them on the same line you would a normal entry. So for example:

```
Defaults rootpw
```

This would make all commands require entering root's password.
However you could do the following instead:

```
Defaults!/bin/bash rootpw
```

This would instead use root's password only when running `/bin/bash`.

There are a lot of other ways to control this behavior, but you should consult `man 5 sudoers` for the details.

Comment: Oh...kay, but Ubuntu Quantal's `/etc/sudoers` calls neither `rootpw` nor `runaspw`. Where does the default come from?

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't use root's password for sudo.

Comment: Okay, you didn't get the question. Meanwhile I figured out that `sudo` by default asks the invoking users password (as used in Ubuntu), then checks `/etc/sudoers` for allowance. Other distros like OpenSUSE explicitly set `Default targetpw` making `sudo` act like `su`.