# Prefer sudo over su by using a separate user with full sudo "privileges"?

Tags: security, sudo, root, su

Can I combine the security of `su` (which is in my view, and broadly speaking: not everybody can be root) and the convenience of `sudo` (password timeout) if I:

1. create a user "admin" (for example)
2. give ONLY this user full sudo (`admin ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL`)
3. instead of using `su` (when logged in as "johndoe") I use `sudo -u admin mycommand`

Wouldn't that combine both advantages or do I forget something?

Recently I read that there are disadvantages of `sudo` in terms of security ([here](http://www.enterprisenetworkingplanet.com/netsecur/article.php/3641911/Using-sudo-to-Keep-Admins-Honest--sudont.htm) and elsewhere) and it made me think about my approach.

I **don't** want to get into the topic whether to prefer `su` over `sudo` in general (or vice versa).

In **my** opinion it's convenient that `sudo` lets you run commands for some minutes without having to enter the password and after timeout requests it again. 
In contrast, you can forget to close the shell where you've run `su`; it shouldn't be, but people forget -- that's reality.

Comment: Wouldn't `sudo -u admin foo` run `foo` as `admin`, and not as `root`? Was that what you wanted? Or did you mean you'd do `sudo -u admin sudo something`...? I'm not sure what you mean with "not everybody can be root" as a feature of `su` in specific: doesn't `sudo` give you more fine-grained control on what commands your users can run?

Comment: yes, sudo is fine grained, but sometime to fine grained?! As simplified example - in private: I dont want to whitelist every command, but don't want to work as root either. My thinking is: I have to use a different password, but NOT the root password (as it would be with su)
(maybe I have to say, I'm starting with Linux administration and want to get a grip on that whole topic. Thats why I searched and read some articles but didn't found an really good bestPractice/explaination on this, so if you got links I would be grateful)

Comment: What is the advantage of not using the root password, if you're granting access to privileged commands such as `passwd -u root`?

Comment: ... and I thought "sudo -u admin COMMAND" would be sufficient, but yes, maybe it has to be "sudo -u admin sudo COMMAND" (maybe this could be aliased)

Comment: @sourcejedi I mean, that "root" and "admin" are the same person. But using sudo instead of using su gives me the "safetynet" (?) of having a timeout

Comment: I don't get the part about "a different a password but not the root password" either if you want to allow running arbitrary commands as root anyway. Just set `Defaults rootpw` or `Defaults targetpw` and have `sudo` ask for the password of the user whose powers you're going to use, and not the password of the user using those powers (running `sudo`)

Comment: @ilkkachu thank you!! for the hint with the "Defaults" option. (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71755/where-to-configure-which-password-sudo-needs) 
I will have to read more about that.